# O que é defenestrar?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, verbos

Recentemente ouvi o verbo "defenestrar" e não entendi seu significado, então, fica a dúvida: qual seu significado, de onde esta palavra surgiu e esta palavra realmente existe no vocabulário brasileiro ou é apenas uma gíria?

A frase dita pela pessoa foi a seguinte:

> Um dia eu ainda defenestro você!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Defenestrar" significa "jogar (algo) pela janela". Mais precisamente (segundo o [dicionário Houaiss](http://houaiss.uol.com.br/busca?palavra=defenestrar)):

> **defenestrar**
>
> *verbo (a1958)*
>
> 1 ( t.d. ) atirar (alguém ou algo) janela afora,
> violentamente

A etmologia da palavra, segundo também o próprio dicionário, é o idioma francês, com a palavra *défenestrer* (1564), ou o ato de 'retirar as janelas de' (sendo que "janela" em francês é "*fenêtre*"). Entretanto, não tenho informações sobre quando essa expressão passou a ser utilizada em Português.

Comment: Olá @luiz-vieira, de onde esta palavra surgiu e esta palavra realmente existe no vocabulário brasileiro ou é apenas uma gíria?

Comment: Ah, desculpe, não tinha visto a edição.

Comment: @MateusDemboski Todas as pessoas que eu conheci que sabiam dessa palavra (aqui no Brasil) foi por causa dessa crônica do Luís Fernando Veríssimo: http://defenestracaooumatodecoragem.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/cronica-de-luis-fernando-verissimo.html

Comment: É frequentemente usada em jornais para se referir à saída (queda) de um ministro ou autoridade do gênero.

Answer (score 0):

[Defenestrar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestra%C3%A7%C3%A3o), como já foi dito, é o ato de atirar algo por uma janela.

Quanto à origem de defenestrar, acredito que parte deve-se aos famosos incidentes chamados de [Defenestrações de Praga](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestra%C3%A7%C3%B5es_de_Praga), ocorridos em 1419 e 1618.

Sobre a utilização no português, já vi utilizarem o termo para gerar uma certa "preocupação" ao interlocutor, como uma forma de brincadeira, já que defenestrar é, de maneira geral, desconhecido às pessoas. Talvez este seja o seu caso!